# Хорошая ли практика когда @Service вызывает собственные методы

Tags: spring, mvc, rest

У меня есть сервис для обработки изображений получаемых разными путями в контроллере. (по ссылке, загрузка с ПК или JSON)

и нужно преобразовывать разный входной формат в MultipartFile и промежуточно так же сжимать до размера 100 на 100

в итоге я вынес в сервис 4 метода.

```
public interface HandlerService {
    BufferedImage сжимаетФото(Image originalImage, int scaledWidth, int scaledHeight, boolean preserveAlpha);

    Boolean валидация(String imageString);

    MultipartFile преобразуетСсылку (URL requestURL) throws IOException;

    MultipartFile преобразуетJSON(String formWrapper) throws IOException;

}
```

но в контроллере у меня используется только 2 метода: преобразуетСсылку  и преобразуетJSON.

а остальные два вызваются уже внутри этих методов втрутри класса @servise.

Как лучше поступить? убрать из интерфейса эти 2 метода (сжимаетФото, валидация) и оставить только внутри класса @Service или можно оставить как есть?

Comment: интерфейс имплементирует один класс? что предполагает тех.задание? какие из преобразований необходимы? т.е. что есть на входе и что на выходе? вызов собственных методов класса соответствует GRASP-паттерну High Cohesion, посему никаких проблем нет. должны ли методы быть публичными  (соответственно быть определены в интерфейсе) - абсолютно другой вопрос. ответ на него зависит от того, что я спросил в самом начале)

Comment: Да интерфейс имплементирует один класс. В тех задании можно передать в контроллер изображение разными путями (через ссылку, json или с ПК и нужно сконвертировать миниатюры изображений + валидация что это именно изображения а не другие файлы). Преобразования : ссылка в изоюражение, json base64 в изображение и потом уже сжатие в миниатюру.

Comment: ну вы сами ответили на первую часть вопроса. не нужно оставлять неиспользуемые методы в интерфейсе, а все методы, которые используются исключтельно внутри сервиса, нужно сделать приватными.

Comment: да спасибо так и сделаю.